# It is possible to install USIM Application onto SIM card?

Tags: sim

In my case, SIM card is Sysmocom Sysmo-SIM-SJS1. The same Sysmocom provide Sysmo-USIM-SJS1. I was wondering if Sysmo-SIM kit can be used as Sysmo-USIM kit by installing USIM Application onto the SIM card.

Thank you.